# PWA SwUpdate checkForUpdate() does nothing

Tags: angular, optimization, progressive-web-apps

I read the documentation of the service worker in angular and I have difficulties to understand the purpose of the method checkForUpdate().

Is there any usage for checkForUpdate(), as far as I understand it correctly, this method returns a Promise which indicates if the check completed successfully, but doesn't indicate if a new version is available or not.

My questions:

- Without checkForUpdate() the download of the new version would still take place right?
- Is there an example where checkForUpdate() is useful?

Not directly related question:

- The update of the pwa is slow (~20-30 seconds), is there any possiblity to make the update process faster?

Answer (score 1):

#### About updates

Yes the service worker will still download the update.. but you need to trigger the activation of the update otherwise the old version will still be used.

eg.

```
this.serviceWorkerUpdates.checkForUpdate().then(() => {
 /*
   do stuff here..
 you might want to run 
 this.serviceWorkerUpdates.available.subscribe()
 and if there are new versions.. take some action.. 
*/
}));
```

The automatic update done by the service worker will only trigger once and you might want to do manual checks to see if a new version has been deployed..

Perhaps you have a admin app where users don't really reload the app that often but you still need them to have the latest version.

#### Slow updates

Why the update is slow *might* be due to the appState not being stable until 20-30 sec passes.. depends on your app.

What you could try is to register the service worker instantly instead of having it waiting for the app to get stable

Do that by using the strategy called `registerImmediately`.

```
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: environment.production,
      registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately',
    }),
```

Comment: But the documentation on the angular page says that checkForUpdate doesn't tell if a new version is available or not, so your suggestion to check manually if a new version has been deployed or not can't be handled with checkForUpdate right?

Comment: And your example calling activateUpdate before available is I think wrong, because if the update files are not present, when activateUpdate is called, then nothing will happen right?

Comment: You are correct.. I typed the wrong method.. I have updated to `checkForUpdate` :)

Comment: The idea is that you first trigger `checkForUpdate` and then subscribe to the `this.serviceWorkerUpdates.available.subscribe()`

Comment: @YusufIpek does this solve your initial question?